# how to real my Location in MapKit xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I want to create one app that show me my location in google map but when run this app don't show me my location and show another location in san francisco !!! why don't show me my location in my city??? this is my code :

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: are you sure you're not in SanFrancisco?

Comment: Running from Xcode? Got location simulation turned on?

Comment: yes my friend I'm sure. maybe this is for run with simulator???

Comment: @mamal10 yes, you're right. you should run it on device

Comment: my friend one question how to put pin in google maps and show latitude/longitude of that pid in NSLog???

Comment: @mamal10 http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: thanks my friend. don't have another site that guide me?

Comment: @mamal10 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html